# Twilio Java TwilioRestException MessageFactory Class Not Found

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying Twilio Server Side SDK for Java. I downloaded the twilio-java-sdk-7.0.0-rc-10-jar-with-dependencies.jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.twilio.sdk%22%20AND%20a%3A%22twilio-java-sdk%22) and took sample code from [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java#using). But couldn't found the following classes anywhere. I tried looking for it on google also but no help.

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay whatever you are saying is correct. But Try this, I had downloaded the jar with dependencies for 6.3.0 and the classes which you are finding is available in that jar.

Comment: great, got it working. I was trying to use version 7.x instead of 6.x... thanks...

Comment: @tina aha, You have to mark it as answer not upvote. Thanks anyway

Comment: @foxt7ot, I am trying a similar implementation and having some trouble. Can you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809117/twilio-sms-api-message-not-being-sent-shows-no-error