# Twilio SMS API message not being sent, shows no error

Tags: java, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio for sending SMS from my Java Spring MVC Web Application.
I have followed the instructions in the page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java. I have the following dependency added in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
  <version>(7.0,7.9)</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have a method to send SMS as follows:

```
public String sendMessage(ModelMap model) 
    {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+1**********"),
        new PhoneNumber("+15005550006"), 
             "testing sms sending").create();
    System.out.println(message.getSid());
    return message.getSid();
  }
```

I have the following imports also:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
```

I don't get any error in while running the code, but SMS is not being received at the number. I use a valid US number for recipient. Is there any solution for this....

if I print the message status, i get: `queued`. I am able to get a valid sid also.

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger?quickDate=24)? Or any signs of messages in the [Twilio SMS log](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs)?

Comment: @philnash I am new to this Twilio, I don't see any errors at my end, no exceptions

Comment: That's why I asked about the Twilio logs, you can see if there were issues on the Twilio side in both the debugger and SMS log. Check out the links from my previous comment.

Comment: I didn't find anything there

Comment: Do you call the `sendMessage` anywhere?

Comment: The above are the only codes I use related to Twilio, I could only find these

Comment: You're going to need to call the method in order to send the message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129083/discussion-between-geo-thomas-and-philnash).

Comment: Also answered in chat, but repeating here. Test credentials can be used to test that your code worked and will respond successfully if you do the right thing. They will not actually send a message though. You can use your production credentials for no cost if you haven't upgraded your account yet.